# How to remove last char from python IO stream

Tags: python, iostream

```
import io
my_list = [{'id': 1, 'updated_at': 20}, {'id': 2, 'updated_at': 10} ]
string_out = io.StringIO()
first_obj = my_list[0]
keys = first_obj.keys()
for i in keys:
    string_out.write(i)
    string_out.write(",")

print(string_out.getvalue())
```

OutPut:-  id,updated_at,

i Want to remove last ","(Comma) from my stream.?

I want to remove the last character that could be Anything here i have used command just for example purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just write using `join` with `,` like,

```
>>> import io
>>> my_list = [{'id': 1, 'updated_at': 20}, {'id': 2, 'updated_at': 10} ]
>>> string_out = io.StringIO()
>>> first_obj = my_list[0]
>>> keys = first_obj.keys()
>>> string_out.write(','.join(keys))
13
>>> print(string_out.getvalue())
id,updated_at
>>>
```

or better yet,

```
>>> string_out = io.StringIO()
>>> my_list
[{'id': 1, 'updated_at': 20}, {'id': 2, 'updated_at': 10}]
>>> for idx,d in enumerate(my_list):
...   if idx == 0:
...     string_out.write(','.join(d.keys()) + '\n')
...   string_out.write(','.join(str(x) for x in d.values()) + '\n')
... 
14
5
5
>>> print(string_out.getvalue())
id,updated_at
1,20
2,10
```

Comment: last character could be anything command is just for example purposes

Comment: I don't understand. Could you paste a realistic example with the question ? I mean, the reason you are getting that last character is you are joining it wrong. Join it properly and you won't get that extra in the end

Comment: No problem. Glad i could be of help

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by making the comma adding line before the element and having a flag to ensure comma is not added before the first element

```
import io
my_list = [{'id': 1, 'updated_at': 20}, {'id': 2, 'updated_at': 10} ]
string_out = io.StringIO()
first_obj = my_list[0]
keys = first_obj.keys()
flag=0
for i in keys:
    if(flag==0):
        flag=1
    else:
        string_out.write(",")

    string_out.write(i)    


print(string_out.getvalue())
```

Comment: last character could be anything command is just for example purposes

Comment: You could change as required in the code for last char

Comment: I have just rearranged your writes and added a flag to check if it is first iteration

Comment: Thanks for the Help got it